# MS Access2010 can not save forms after setting a module object in VBA

Tags: forms, vba, module

I'm using MS Access 2010 and dynamically creating subforms via VBA with control buttons that have VBA script.  I am able to create the forms and program the VBA scripts in the buttons.  My problem is I am unable to save the form.

The problem is when I "Set" the module object, the DoCmD.Close does not save the form.  I have added the "Mirosoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" in the References.

I have been searching for the past week and cant seem to find the answer.

```
Sub fromButtonTest()

Dim frm As Form
Dim cntB As Control
Dim mdl As Module

Set frm = CreateForm
Set cntB = CreateControl(frm.Name, acCommandButton, acDetail, , 200, 500)
Set mdl = frm.Module

''
'Add line codes goes here
''
DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name, acSaveYes
End Sub
```